# Ingress (Kubernetes) working only with path "/"

Tags: spring-boot, controller, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

This is my ingress.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spring-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "Content-Type"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-project.app.loc
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: user-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

This is my UserController.java file:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/hello1")
    public String sayHello1() {
        return "Hello World 1!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello2")
    public String sayHello2() {
        return "Hello World 2!";
    }

}
```

This setup works. For example, if I call:
`curl my-project.app.loc/hello1`
I get Hello World 1!

However, my goal is to call:
`curl my-project.app.loc/users/hello1`
and get Hello World 1!

I found two working solutions:

- Add `@RequestMapping("/users")` annotation in my UserController class.

  Or
- Add `server.servlet.context-path=/users` in application.properties file.

All this, with "/" path in Ingress file.

But I saw many example on Internet in which people use `path: /users` in ingress.yaml file, without using @RequestMapping annotation or editing application.properties.

I would like to know why this setup doesn't work for me and what could I do to make it work. As you can see, I've also used the rewrite-target annotation.

Thank you all in advance.

Solution:
I solved using this configuration for ingress.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spring-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-project.app.loc
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: user-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: In my case context-path: /api/dev & the spring controller has /process In ingress rewrite-target: /$1 & path: /api/dev/process/(.*) I get 404